# Disable the entry in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, disabled-control

Is it possible to disable the options in sharepoint?

For an example, I have created a list for leave request and a workflow associated to it. Now what I want is, once the leave is applied and sent for approval, the user should not be able to make changes to that particular entry or delete it. If the user still wants to make changes to it, then there is an option to cancel it, only when the leave is approved. Again, once he has applied for cancellation, and submits the request for cancellation, then that particular entry should get disabled and user should not be able to  make changes to it.

I have tried to search for options in sharepoint but of no use and I am unsure if we can do this using sharepoint designer.

Is there any such privilege in Sharepoint or Sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 0):

I would put some form validation saying if field == approved they are unable to save the record. This means if they do edit it they will be unable to save as the approve field should be hidden from the form but you can put a useful message in place saying they should cancel and then re-apply for the holiday.

Just google form or field validation SharePoint.

If you want the option to cancel then you should have a second workflow the user can start manually to cancel the holiday.

In terms of stopping deletion: I would have a special permission level (Contribute no delete) for this specific list that stops all general users from deleting any items. You want this in place as you will want to keep track of whats happened from an auditing perspective.

I would do it the above way as when you start setting permissions on each item it becomes cumbersome. The other option is to use flow and I am pretty sure you would be able to perform all of this within a single flow.

Cheers

Truezplaya

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will give them a try, though I have already tried the very first point and it is good when the condition is not dependent on the workflow. For an example,I want that if [Last Availed Leave]+[Number of days requested]<=[Accrued Leaves], then only the person should be able to apply for the leave.

Comment: Here what is happening, that the [Last Availed Leave] is calculated by the workflow, therefore if I put the check in the workflow, then there is no option to prompt for an error and pause the workflow until the number of days are changed. This why the workflow keeps running with the negative value once the condition is violated.                                                                                                                     
On the other hand, if I set the formula for last availed in the SharePoint, then certain specific conditions are not met by the workflow.

Comment: I understand that we can use "Contribute, no Delete", but I am unable to find that option.

Comment: You will need to create the contribute no delete permission level, It's not something that comes with SharePoint, The previous comments allude to you doing more than what you have described in a previous post. If you are trying to track how many days they have as well your talking multiple lists, I wouldn't manage that figure on the same list

Comment: I was able to create a new custom permission level, contribute-no delete in sharepoint and apply it on the user group.